# background:url(repeat_bg.png) repeat-y, url(repeat_bg_right_side.png) top right repeat-y; in ie8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, repeat

```
body{




background:url(repeat_bg.png) repeat-y, url(repeat_bg_right_side.png) top right repeat-y;
}
```

is there a way i could make this work in ie8 ? or is this not supported by ie8 ( i'm a newb ). thanks for your time !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8 doesn't support multiple backgrounds. Your best bet is to create an outer container `div` and put one background on body and one on the container div:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        ...
    </div>
</body>
```

with the CSS:

```
body {
    background: url(repeat_bg.png) top left repeat-y;
    padding: 0;
}

#container {
    background: url(repeat_bg_right_side.png) top right repeat-y;
}
```

(You need the `padding: 0` because some browsers put padding on `body` by default which would cause the two images to not line up.)